# Glide centerCrop() not working with CustomTarget

Tags: android, android-glide, android-bitmap

I'm getting "center inside" instead of "center crop"
[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </FrameLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load("https://www.lomsnesvet.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/08/Kitten-Blog-1600x2400.jpg")
                .centerCrop()
                .into(object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                })
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

**Requirements**:

- the imageViews are not available in case of push notification so `.into(CustomTarget<>)` is used instead of `.into(imageView)`
- Callbacks on success and failure are necessary

Comment: What is your expected output? I think that this is working fine. Also, you can use scaleType on ImageView with centerCrop value.

Comment: @SlothCoding what's showing right now is centerInside, not centerCrop. CenterInside is desirable in some other parts of my app. The app would be hardly maintainable if one had to use Glide + imageview XML configuration

Answer (score 5):

For some unknown reason to me there is an issue when you use `CustomTarget<Bitmap>` inside `into()`. If you just use it like this:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("https://www.lomsnesvet.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/08/Kitten-Blog-1600x2400.jpg")
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
```

This works and it shows image as `centerCrop()`. But when you use `CustomTarget<Bitmap>` it ignores that method. What you can do is this:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("https://www.lomsnesvet.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/08/Kitten-Blog-1600x2400.jpg")
            .centerCrop()
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }
            });
```

And then you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. I just think it's unnecessary work for developers. The library that is Glide here should handle this or at least make it more explicit in documentation

Comment: @SlothCoding Would you know the reason behind why Glide transformation like `centerCrop()` doesn't work when the `CustomTarget<Bitmap>` is inside `into()`? I ran into same issue, but this time using `centerInside()`. Using `centerCrop()` works though.

Comment: This might also help someone.. what also worked for me is setting the attribute `android:scaleType="centerInside"` (in my case) in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by adding set dimensions for the generated bitmap, then center crop worked. I needed to set the image for a NavigationView drawer header background which doesn't allow you to set scale like in the prev example, so this was my workaround.

```
Glide.with(this)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(currentSet.getVideo())
                            .centerCrop()
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(1280, 720))
                            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                                    headerLinearLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resource));
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                                }
                            });
```